# Extract the data from a SelectedItem event from a LINQ filled DataGrid

Tags: c#, .net, linq, datagrid, textbox

I have a table "Cards" in a database with tables "Cards" and "Customers". Cards contains CustomerID, Number and Ammount. After that, I used ADO.NET to make use of `DataGrid`, `TextBox`, etc.

I dropped a `DataGrid` and a `TextBox` as a Search Criteria. When a button is pressed, the `DataGrid` is loaded with the LINQ:

```
string searchString = this.CustomerIDTextBox.Text();
using (var ctx = new bdCustomerEntities()){
    var result = from t in ctx.Cards
                 join t_customer in ctx.Customer on t.CustomerID equals t_customer.id
                 where t.CustomerID == searchString
                 select new
                 {
                     number = t.number,
                     ammount = t.ammount,
                     CustomerID = t.Customer.id
                 };
    /*Fill datagrid*/
    this.CardsDataGrid.ItemsSource = result.ToList();
}
```

The problem comes when I made a `MouseDoubleClick` event in the `CardsDataGrid` to select the row and fill two `TextBox`es, one with the Ammount data and the other one with Number.

I tried this code but it fails to show the data in the `TextBox`es:

```
Cards selected = this.cardsDataGrid.SelectedItem as Cards;
this.numberTextBox.Text = selected.Number.ToString();
this.ammountTextBox.Text = seleccionado.Ammount.ToString();
```

I made a `MessageBox.Show` after the `Cards selected = ...` line to see the content on the `SelectedItem`, and it shows something like this:

```
{number = 13, ammount = 3500 , CustomerID = 1456 }
```

My problem is that, I can't "extract" the `SelectedItem` because of the format created - maybe by the LINQ? - and put that in the `TextBox`es.

Something I noticed, when I made this change to the above code:

```
Cards selected = (Cards) this.cardsDataGrid.SelectedItem ;
```

It shows:

> System.InvalidCastException:Unable to cast object of type
>   '[System.Int32,System.Int32,System.String]' to type
>   'bdCustomer.Cards'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your LINK is returning an anonymous type not the `Cards` type, and there is no cast available between the anonymous type and the `Cards` type, which is what the error is telling you.

Change your LINQ to this:

```
var result = from t in ctx.Cards
             join t_customer in ctx.Customer on t.CustomerID equals t_customer.id
             where t.CustomerID == searchString
             select t;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You were right! I fixed the problem. Now I can continue the project.

Answer (score 0):

In your query result, you return an anonymous type not Cards type and this is the reason you receive InvalidCastException.
You can return the Cards type from your DBSet:

```
from t in ctx.Cards
join t_customer in ctx.Customer on t.CustomerID equals t_customer.id
where t.CustomerID == searchString
select t;
```

Comment: Why do we need to create a new object and assign it the exact same values of the current object? Simply select the current object itself. Otherwise a good answer.

Comment: Yes, my mistake, I didn't notice he or she query over Cards table.

Comment: Thanks for the help too! I was able to fix it.